# Inheriting from abstract class, using methods with private variables

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In a simplified version, I have the following:

```
abstract class Days
{
  private readonly int _amount;

  protected virtual void UpdateAmount()
  {
    Proccess();
  }

  protected virtual void Process()
  {
    _amount += 1; 
  }
}
```

The problem is I need to create a class which inherits from Days, in which I need to change the functionality of UpdateAmounts() but still use the same functionality from Process(). Since Process uses a private field, is there anyway to do this without just copying and pasting the code from Process() into my child class? It wont let me use base.Process() because the method references a private field.

Comment: "It wont let me use base.Process()" - what is "it" that blocks you from using protected method? Can you please post sample of what you are trying to achieve and how it fails (you are already mentioned `base.Process()` otherwise should be duplicate of some existing question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747711/call-base-function-then-inherited-function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be able to use `base.Process()` because it is `protected`, it doesn't matter if it uses private fields

```
class MyClass : Days
{    
    protected override void UpdateAmount()
    {
        base.Process();
    }
}
```

This code works

Comment: You're  correct, I was missing the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @mameesh, codroipo - would you mind to edit question so it matches the answer? So far question have just random claim that this code does not work...