# Call a method in every derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is it a way to call a method in each derived class, hierarchically?

I need it to use it with user scripts, so i cant force the user to call base.Update();

I need it to be called whether he did the base call or not.

```
    public class Base
    {
        public virtual void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BASE UPDATE");
            ;
        }
    }
    public class Base2 : Base
    {
        public override void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BASE2 UPDATE");
            ;
        }
    }
    public class Base3 : Base2
    {
        public override void Update()
        {
            // base.Update() ? no no, i want to do it for User Scripts so i cant force user to call base.Update()
            Console.WriteLine("BASE3 UPDATE");
        }
    }
    public class TestClass
    {
        public void DoTheTest()
        {
            Base3 instance = new Base3();
            instance.Update();
            // the output i need:
            /*
                BASE UPDATE
                BASE2 UPDATE
                BASE3 UPDATE
            */

        }
    }
```

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate - that answer shows how to call a single base method - OP wants to hierarchically call all overridden base methods without actually coding it.

Comment: Nope, C# provides no way to ensure this. The *template pattern* as demonstrated in the [link in Mark Phillips' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747711/call-base-function-then-inherited-function) is your best bet, even if it does not fit 100%.

Comment: The language doesn't work that way. What are you trying to do, rewrite Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant way but it works

```
public interface IUpdateHandler
{
    void UpdateHandler();
}

public class Base : IUpdateHandler
{
    public Base()
    {
        OnUpdate += (s, e) => UpdateHandler();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        OnUpdate(this, null);
    }

    public void UpdateHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BASE UPDATE");
    }

    protected event EventHandler OnUpdate;
}

public class Base2 : Base, IUpdateHandler
{
    public Base2()
    {
        OnUpdate += (sender, args) => UpdateHandler();
    }

    public new void UpdateHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BASE2 UPDATE");
    }
}

public class Base3 : Base2, IUpdateHandler
{
    public Base3()
    {
        OnUpdate += (sender, args) => UpdateHandler();
    }

    public new void UpdateHandler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BASE3 UPDATE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have an object of class Base, or of a derived class from Base and
you want to call all available Update() functions in a hierarchical order, from top to bottom (base1 / base2 / base3)

From any object you can get the Type object. You can also ask for the base class type. From each Type object you can ask if it knows a method with a specific name. If it does, you can call this method.

- Object.GetType()
- Type.BaseType
- Type.GetMethod(string)
- MethodInfo.Invoke

.

```
public void UpdateHierarchical(Base someObject)
{
    UpdateHierarchical(someObject.GetType(), someObject);
}

private void UpdateHierarchical(Type type, object obj)
    // if the object has a base class
    // call this function recursively with type = base type
    // if this type has has an Update, call it,

    Type type = obj.GetType();        // the type of obj
    Type baseType = type.BaseType();  // the base type of obj
    if (baseType != null)             // there is a base type
        UpdateHierarchical(baseType, obj);

    // now that all base Update() are called,
    // check if this type has an Update
    MethodInfo updateInfo = type.GetMethod("Update")
    if (updateInfo != null)
    {   // this type has an Update()
        updateInfo.Invoice(obj, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, i lost all my reputation recently for some rage post, but i upvoted this one it just doesnt show.