# How to correctly inherit Unity's callback functions like Awake(), Start() and Update and FixedUpdate()?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I've created a parent class that I expect to have all functions related to testing if the GameObject is grounded, in water, on air, etc... given that this functions will be used by the player as well as other GameObjects. However, the child class seems not to inherit properly the functions.

The parent script it's as follows:

```
public class CharacterPhysic : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] protected Transform groundPoints;
  float grounRadius;
  private void Start ()
  {
     whatIsGround = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
     groundRadius = 0.01f;
  }
  protected bool IsGrounded()
  {
     Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundPoints.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
     if (colliders.Length > 0)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else return false;
  }
  private void FixedUpdate()
  {
     Debug.Log(IsGrounded());
  }
}
```

And the children script is just:

```
public class ErrantMove : CharacterPhysic {
  private void FixedUpdate()
  {
     Debug.Log(IsGrounded());
  }
}
```

When added the first script as a component to a Gameobject (after defining the grounPoint) the `Debug.Log(IsGrounded());` returns **TRUE**

However, when added the second script as a component to the same Gameobject (after defining the grounPoint and remove the first script) the `Debug.Log(IsGrounded());` returns **FALSE** even in the same circumstances.

I'm expecting to be able to add movement functions into the second script but this depends on the ability to test if it is grounded.

Comment: Is your `whatIsGround` initialized properly? Did you tried to debug? Also in `IsGrounded` method you can write just `return colliders.Length > 0` at the end.

Comment: I could swear there was a dupe target for this somewhere, but if @Programmer can't find it, then it might not exist.

Comment: @Draco18s That's right. I've seen that question before but couldn't find it again. I have even answered one before. I've also noticed questions I've answered before gone missing. Some either deleted by OP or by the *community* which I assume to be a mod.

Comment: @Programmer Or possibly on a different site? Eg. game dev or unity answers? But yeah, I *know* I've seen this before.

Comment: Nope. It was here because I even remember answering one. I don't answer on Unity  site or gamedev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Start` method will not be executed in child class. Move it into child class if you are not going to use parent class.

```
public class ErrantMove : CharacterPhysic {

  protected void Start ()
  {
     whatIsGround = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
     groundRadius = 0.01f;
  }

  private void FixedUpdate()
  {
     Debug.Log(IsGrounded());
  }

}
```

You can notice that if you will have more than one child classes, you will be forced to initialize base class's `Start` method in every child class, so you can create an `virtual Start` method, then call it inside child classes:

```
public class CharacterPhysic : MonoBehaviour {
  . . .
  protected virtual void Start ()
  {
     whatIsGround = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
     groundRadius = 0.01f;
  }
  protected bool IsGrounded()
  {
     Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundPoints.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
     return colliders.Length > 0;
  }
  . . .
}

public class ErrantMove : CharacterPhysic {

  protected override void Start()
  {
      base.Start();
  }

  private void FixedUpdate()
  {
     Debug.Log(IsGrounded());
  }

}
```

you can go either `virtual/override` approach, or use `new` keyword to "unhide" child class's `Start` method (I'm not sure how `new` will behave in unity, so better go with first one).

Comment: This is not true. It will be executed in the child class if done properly.

Comment: If the inheritance is done [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747711/call-base-function-then-inherited-function) by using the correct keywords: `virtual` and `override`.  When the parent function is called, you call the base function.....

Comment: @Programmer I just didn't go into the details. But I will edit anyway. My main goal was to show OP that his base Start will not be executed inside child class.

Answer (score 13):

You can properly inherit Unity's callback functions such as `Awake`, `Start`  and `Update` like you would with a normal C# inheritance paradigm. It's very simply.

Make the all the callback functions for the base class to be `virtual`:

```
public class YourBaseClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Awake Base");

    }

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start Base");
    }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Update Base");
    }

    protected virtual void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log("FixedUpdate Base");
    }
}
```

For the parent class that will derive from the base class, add the callback functions too but mark them as `override`. If you need the base function to be called, call it with `base.FunctionName` before doing anything else in the parent function:

```
public class Parent : YourBaseClass
{
    protected override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();
        Debug.Log("Awake Parent");
    }

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        Debug.Log("Start Parent");
    }

    protected override void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
        Debug.Log("Update Parent");
    }

    protected override void FixedUpdate()
    {
        base.FixedUpdate();
        Debug.Log("FixedUpdate Parent");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When tested in Unity version 2020.1.21f, `protected` callback functions like `Start` will automatically be executed in their child classes. There is no need to declare a function as `virtual`, you should only do that if you intend to override the function in a subclass.

```
public class ParentClass : MonoBehavior
{
    protected void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello, my class is ");
        Debug.Log(this.GetType());
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    //empty class
}

public class GameManager : MonoBehavior
{
    //childPrefab is a prefab containing the ChildClass script as a component
    Object.Instantiate(childPrefab);
}
```

Upon instantiating the childPrefab containing the ChildClass script, the object will print, `"Hello, my class is ChildClass"`.

As for your example, the only thing you would need to do to fix that code is change your `Start` function to `protected`. That will ensure that `Start` is inherited by `ErrantMove`. Additionally, if you don't intend to use `FixedUpdate` for anything other than checking `IsGrounded()`, you could mark `FixedUpdate` as protected, and then delete it from your subclass.

If you want to add additional functionality to `FixedUpdate` in your subclass, then you will need follow the advice of the other answerers and use `virtual`, `override`, and `base.FixedUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

this works if inheritance exists

```
protected override void Awake()
{
    //Base Class
    base.Awake();
    DoSomething();
}

protected override void Update()
{
    base.Update();
}

private void DoSomething(){ "Do Whatever" }
```