# A child object cant add a gameobject to his parent (child gets the object with trigger-collider)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

## Hi,

i have a problem with my 2d unity project.

### What was my goal:

I want to have a player with an extra Collider. This Collider should put every gameObject with the tag "Stone" in a list.

### What i tried:

I made another Object that is the child of my player object.
The Child Object has a round 2d Collider (set as a trigger) and should put everything that has the tag "Stone" in a list of gameObjects in his parent. That gave me an error(see below for more details) as soon as i collided with a stone.
Then i tried putting it in a list in the child object and it worked. i cant really image why it works in the child and not in the parent.

#### Here are the scripts:

###### Relevant part of the stompRadiusCollScript(child):

```cs
public class stompRadiusCollScript : bendingScript
{
    private GameObject parent;
    private List<GameObject> colls;
    void Start()
    {
        colls = new List<GameObject>();
        parent = base.gameObject;
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D givenCollider)
    {
        if (givenCollider.tag == "Stone")
        {
            GameObject co = givenCollider.gameObject;
            //is able to add in Child List
            colls.Add(co);
            //cannot add in parent list
            //throws error
            currCollisions.Add(co);
        }
    }
```

###### What was the error message:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
stompRadiusCollScript.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D givenCollider)
```

###### Relevant Code from bendingScript(parent):

```
public class bendingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected List<GameObject> currCollisions;
    public Collider2D coll;
    private System.DateTime _lastTimeStompAttack;
    private float _stompAttackMinDelayInMs = 500f;
    private float _forceForStone = 100f;
    void Start()
    {
        currCollisions = new List<GameObject>();
        coll  = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        _lastTimeStompAttack = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

###### additional information:

- The objects with the tags stone have a rigidbody2d and a circlecollider2d

### Question:

How do i get my all stone collisions as gameObjects in a list in the parent (bendingScript)?

Comment: You aren't initializing `currCollisions` in `stompRadiusCollScript` because `bendingScript.Start` is hidden. Does this answer your question? [How to correctly inherit Unity's callback functions like Awake(), Start() and Update and FixedUpdate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076669/how-to-correctly-inherit-unitys-callback-functions-like-awake-start-and-up)

Comment: ### That fixed one problem. thank you.
but i somehow create 2 objects and in that way i create 2 seperate lists.
the child has another list than the parent. <br>
###### what i added in the parent:
`protected virtual void Start()`
###### what i added int the child:
`protected override void Start() {base.Start;}`
I kinda know how inheriting does on a console app, but how does it work here?
As far as i know the child is an advanced version of the parent, so how can i only add the child in the world? Or am i missunderstanding somthing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a list in the parent object you could keep the list in the child object and access the child object later when required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).