# Insert code from child class method in middle of base class method

Tags: c#

I have an `Event` class in C# which can be extended to different type of child Events.

I'm trying to find an efficient way to extend the parent `Event` Execute method such that code in the child Event's Execute will occur in the middle, so that every child Execute gets some pre and post processing for "free".

I've looked at the `base` option, but seems that will execute the entire method.  Is there a way to do this without having to add a base.PreExecute() and base.PostExecute() to every child class?

Example

```
public class Event
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Logger.Trace(string.Format("Starting {0}", this));

        // want the child Execute to occur here

        Logger.Trace(string.Format("Ending {0}", this));
    }
}

public class CarEvent : Event
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        base.Execute();

        // child specific logic
    }
}
```

Comment: See / possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747717/1043380

Comment: The code from the child needs to be in one method with nothing else. Give the parent a method `public virtual void MiddleStuff() {}`. The child will override it as `public override void MiddleStuff() { /* child middle stuff */ }`. Parent calls it where the middle stuff goes. You can't call part of a method. Don't worry about runtime efficiency with this. It's not a concern.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't find that answer in my initial search.